# Node Server not running

Tags: node.js

I have used below code. i have run the file and there are no errors.  But the server 192.123.1.134:5001 shows 'No data received'.
Kindly help me to find out error in the code.

```
express = require('express');
app = express(); 
config = require('./config/database.js');

var path = require('path');

//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade'); 

router = express.Router();

var routes = require('./user/index'); 
var admin = require('./user/user');
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/user', admin);

http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen('5001','192.123.1.134', function(){
          console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',Date(Date.now() ));
    });
```

index.js

```
var User = require('../model/user.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    User.getuserdetails(function(data) {
    res.render('user', {
                        title: 'Welcome',
                        result : data
                        });
    });

//res.render('index', { title: 'welcome' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

user.js (model)

```
var connection =require("../config/database.js");;

router.getuserdetails = function (req,res){
    var result = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1','', function (err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err

});

}
module.exports = router;
```

database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'aaa',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: Where are you running this app? is it localhost or some external server?

Comment: *“there are no errors”* – You’re not looking for errors. With Node, you need to listen to [error events](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error) in order to get any feedback.

Comment: @abdulbarik i m running on virtual host server 192.123.1.134

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `localhost/127.0.0.1` in the IP address part.

You can access it in LAN using your IP address `192.123.1.134`.

```
server.listen('5001','127.0.0.1', function(){
      console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',Date(Date.now() ));
});
```